# How to define a command that copies another command to a different name?

Tags: macros, csname

I am hoping to create a command that automates this process below

```
\let\oldhat\hat
```

with something in this format:

```
\let\old(ARGUMENT)\(ARGUMENT)
```

I tried

```
\newcommand{\makeold}[1]{
    \expandafter\let\csname old#1\endcsname\csname#1\endcsname}
\makeold{hat} %This should rename \hat to \oldhat
```

but this gives me an error that I have too many `\endcsname`'s. Am I misunderstanding the purpose of `\csname`?

Edit: I had forgotten `\let` in my attempt.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are missing a `\let` and an extra `\expandafter`. This definition works:

```
\newcommand{\makeold}[1]{%
   \expandafter\let
       \csname old#1\expandafter\endcsname
       \csname#1\endcsname
}
```

The execution of a command like this is a bit confusing so let me describe how this command works:

`\makeold{hat}` expands to

```
\expandafter\let\csname oldhat\expandafter\endcsname\csname#1\endcsname
```

Next the first `\expandafter` jumps over the `\let` and expands the `\csname`. Expanding the `\csname` recursively expands any macros until it hits `\endcsname` and forms a macro out of the tokens found this way. In particular, it expands the second `\expandafter` which jumps over the `\endcsname` to expand the second `\csname`, which turns `\csname hat\endcsname` into `\hat`.  What's left over are the tokens `\let\oldhat\hat` which is what you wanted to do.

Answer (score 1):

It's simpler with `etoolbox`:

```latex
\usepackage{etoolbox}

\newcommand{\makeold}[1]{\csletcs{old#1}{#1}}
```